# Linked List - Keeping track of each node

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

I found an algorithm to loop through a sorted linked list and remove the duplicate. I wrote it, it works.

Still, I don't understand how can this work. In the end of the loop, to move forward into the while loop, we do this :

```
currentNode = nextNode
```

How can this not erase the current node ? Why does the linked list is still here ? It feels every node is erased each time by the next, isn't it ?

```
class LinkedList {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

function removeDuplicatesFromLinkedList(linkedList) {
    let currentNode = linkedList;

while(currentNode !== null){
    let nextNode = currentNode.next;
    
    while(nextNode !== null && nextNode.value === currentNode.value){
        nextNode = nextNode.next;
    }
    
    currentNode.next = nextNode
    currentNode= nextNode
    
}
currentNode = linkedList;

return linkedList;

}

exports.LinkedList = LinkedList;
exports.removeDuplicatesFromLinkedList = removeDuplicatesFromLinkedList;
```

Comment: `currentNode` is a variable. In JavaScript you can never mutate an object by a mere *assignment* to a variable. An object only gets mutated when you assign something to a *property* of that object (or a deeper nested property). A variable is a *reference* to the node, and an assignment to a variable merely updates a reference, not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, `linkedList` is never overwritten, so the initial list isn't damaged (because when removing duplicates, the first one is kept, only the following are removed).

Then, `currNode` is just the current pointer, to the current node. Assign a new value to it don't delete the previous node, since it's still referenced through the list head `linkedList`.

What is really missing is the `free` instruction on deleted node - this algo rely on a garbage collector to work without a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this by an example:

```
2 -> 3 -> 3 -> 4
```

Initially `currentNode == 2`. In the first iteration of the loop `nextNode == 3`, which is the next node to current node. The inner while loop doesn't run since `currentNode.value` isn't equal to `nextNode.value`. So we hit:

```
    currentNode.next = nextNode
    currentNode= nextNode
```

This sets the next node of `currentNode` to `NextNode`. So, nothing changes. Then we move current node one forward: `currentNode = nextNode`

In the next iteration though, `nextNode == 3`, while `currentNode == 3` too. Now the inner while loop runs one iteration and moves `nextNode` to 4 and breaks since they aren't equal anymore. Then, `currentNode.next` is set to `nextNode`, which was 4, and after `nextNode` is assigned to `currentNode`.

Since these are all pointers to nodes, nothing is being erased. Just the duplicate values are removed from the chain of linked nodes.